# Appending to .csv file recursively

Tags: c++, file, csv, vector, backtracking

I have a backtracking function that generates combination with repetition, and an additional value of some function that takes combination values as parameters.

Combinations are stored as a vector, therefor, I would love my csv file to have an output with two columns, similiar to this:

```
    vector | result
    1 1 1 1 , 0.25
    1 1 1 2 , 0.2
    …
    4 4 4 4 , 0.16
```

However, my output gets individually split and I only get the last value in the recursion, and looks like this

```
A | B | C | D | E
4   4   4   4 , 0.16
```

Here is the function I'm working with:

```
void backtrack(int a[], std::vector<int> &rez, int i, int n) {

    std::ofstream f;
    f.open ("comb_unsorted.csv");

    if (rez.size() == n) {
        for (auto it = rez.begin(); it != rez.end(); it++)
            f << *it << " ";

        f << ",";
        f << function(rez);
        f << '\n';

        return;
    }

    for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {

        rez.push_back(a[j]);
        backtrack(a, rez, j, n);
        rez.pop_back();

        while (j <= n && a[j] == a[j + 1])
            j++;
    }
    f.close();
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: `backtrack` opens a file, then calls itself recursively. That recursive call attempts to open the same file - that fails, since the file is already opened elsewhere.  You want to open the file outside `backtrack` and pass a reference to it along though all recursive calls.

Comment: Can you please provide the content of a[] (first 5 values at least) and what arguments you pass inside the function for the 1st call?

Comment: @vamirio-chan a[] is an array of {1,1,2,3..n}, for inputed n

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int function(vector<int>& rez) {
   return 1;
}

void backtrack(const int arr[], vector<int>& out, const int arrSize, const size_t maxLength) {
   // You should not do this! This is just an example!
   // In order to open/close file properly - do it outside this function and then pass std::ofstream as 5th argument
   static ofstream file("output.csv");

   if (maxLength == 1) {
      stringstream dataFromOut;
      copy(out.begin(), out.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(dataFromOut, " "));
      for (int j = 0; j < arrSize; j++)
         file << dataFromOut.str() << arr[j] << " , " << function(out) << endl;
      return;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
      out.push_back(arr[i]);
      backtrack(arr, out, arrSize, maxLength - 1);
      out.pop_back();
   }
}

int main() {
   int str[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
   int arrSize = 4;
   vector<int> test;
   backtrack(str, test, arrSize, arrSize);
   return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
1 1 1 1 , 1
1 1 1 2 , 1
1 1 1 3 , 1
1 1 1 4 , 1
1 1 2 1 , 1
1 1 2 2 , 1
1 1 2 3 , 1
1 1 2 4 , 1
1 1 3 1 , 1
1 1 3 2 , 1
1 1 3 3 , 1
1 1 3 4 , 1
1 1 4 1 , 1
1 1 4 2 , 1
1 1 4 3 , 1
1 1 4 4 , 1
1 2 1 1 , 1
1 2 1 2 , 1
1 2 1 3 , 1
1 2 1 4 , 1
1 2 2 1 , 1
1 2 2 2 , 1
1 2 2 3 , 1
1 2 2 4 , 1
1 2 3 1 , 1
1 2 3 2 , 1
1 2 3 3 , 1
1 2 3 4 , 1
1 2 4 1 , 1
1 2 4 2 , 1
1 2 4 3 , 1
1 2 4 4 , 1
1 3 1 1 , 1
1 3 1 2 , 1
1 3 1 3 , 1
1 3 1 4 , 1
1 3 2 1 , 1
1 3 2 2 , 1
1 3 2 3 , 1
1 3 2 4 , 1
1 3 3 1 , 1
1 3 3 2 , 1
1 3 3 3 , 1
1 3 3 4 , 1
1 3 4 1 , 1
1 3 4 2 , 1
1 3 4 3 , 1
1 3 4 4 , 1
1 4 1 1 , 1
1 4 1 2 , 1
1 4 1 3 , 1
1 4 1 4 , 1
1 4 2 1 , 1
1 4 2 2 , 1
1 4 2 3 , 1
1 4 2 4 , 1
1 4 3 1 , 1
1 4 3 2 , 1
1 4 3 3 , 1
1 4 3 4 , 1
1 4 4 1 , 1
1 4 4 2 , 1
1 4 4 3 , 1
1 4 4 4 , 1
2 1 1 1 , 1
2 1 1 2 , 1
2 1 1 3 , 1
2 1 1 4 , 1
2 1 2 1 , 1
2 1 2 2 , 1
2 1 2 3 , 1
2 1 2 4 , 1
2 1 3 1 , 1
2 1 3 2 , 1
2 1 3 3 , 1
2 1 3 4 , 1
2 1 4 1 , 1
2 1 4 2 , 1
2 1 4 3 , 1
2 1 4 4 , 1
2 2 1 1 , 1
2 2 1 2 , 1
2 2 1 3 , 1
2 2 1 4 , 1
2 2 2 1 , 1
2 2 2 2 , 1
2 2 2 3 , 1
2 2 2 4 , 1
2 2 3 1 , 1
2 2 3 2 , 1
2 2 3 3 , 1
2 2 3 4 , 1
2 2 4 1 , 1
2 2 4 2 , 1
2 2 4 3 , 1
2 2 4 4 , 1
2 3 1 1 , 1
2 3 1 2 , 1
2 3 1 3 , 1
2 3 1 4 , 1
2 3 2 1 , 1
2 3 2 2 , 1
2 3 2 3 , 1
2 3 2 4 , 1
2 3 3 1 , 1
2 3 3 2 , 1
2 3 3 3 , 1
2 3 3 4 , 1
2 3 4 1 , 1
2 3 4 2 , 1
2 3 4 3 , 1
2 3 4 4 , 1
2 4 1 1 , 1
2 4 1 2 , 1
2 4 1 3 , 1
2 4 1 4 , 1
2 4 2 1 , 1
2 4 2 2 , 1
2 4 2 3 , 1
2 4 2 4 , 1
2 4 3 1 , 1
2 4 3 2 , 1
2 4 3 3 , 1
2 4 3 4 , 1
2 4 4 1 , 1
2 4 4 2 , 1
2 4 4 3 , 1
2 4 4 4 , 1
3 1 1 1 , 1
3 1 1 2 , 1
3 1 1 3 , 1
3 1 1 4 , 1
3 1 2 1 , 1
3 1 2 2 , 1
3 1 2 3 , 1
3 1 2 4 , 1
3 1 3 1 , 1
3 1 3 2 , 1
3 1 3 3 , 1
3 1 3 4 , 1
3 1 4 1 , 1
3 1 4 2 , 1
3 1 4 3 , 1
3 1 4 4 , 1
3 2 1 1 , 1
3 2 1 2 , 1
3 2 1 3 , 1
3 2 1 4 , 1
3 2 2 1 , 1
3 2 2 2 , 1
3 2 2 3 , 1
3 2 2 4 , 1
3 2 3 1 , 1
3 2 3 2 , 1
3 2 3 3 , 1
3 2 3 4 , 1
3 2 4 1 , 1
3 2 4 2 , 1
3 2 4 3 , 1
3 2 4 4 , 1
3 3 1 1 , 1
3 3 1 2 , 1
3 3 1 3 , 1
3 3 1 4 , 1
3 3 2 1 , 1
3 3 2 2 , 1
3 3 2 3 , 1
3 3 2 4 , 1
3 3 3 1 , 1
3 3 3 2 , 1
3 3 3 3 , 1
3 3 3 4 , 1
3 3 4 1 , 1
3 3 4 2 , 1
3 3 4 3 , 1
3 3 4 4 , 1
3 4 1 1 , 1
3 4 1 2 , 1
3 4 1 3 , 1
3 4 1 4 , 1
3 4 2 1 , 1
3 4 2 2 , 1
3 4 2 3 , 1
3 4 2 4 , 1
3 4 3 1 , 1
3 4 3 2 , 1
3 4 3 3 , 1
3 4 3 4 , 1
3 4 4 1 , 1
3 4 4 2 , 1
3 4 4 3 , 1
3 4 4 4 , 1
4 1 1 1 , 1
4 1 1 2 , 1
4 1 1 3 , 1
4 1 1 4 , 1
4 1 2 1 , 1
4 1 2 2 , 1
4 1 2 3 , 1
4 1 2 4 , 1
4 1 3 1 , 1
4 1 3 2 , 1
4 1 3 3 , 1
4 1 3 4 , 1
4 1 4 1 , 1
4 1 4 2 , 1
4 1 4 3 , 1
4 1 4 4 , 1
4 2 1 1 , 1
4 2 1 2 , 1
4 2 1 3 , 1
4 2 1 4 , 1
4 2 2 1 , 1
4 2 2 2 , 1
4 2 2 3 , 1
4 2 2 4 , 1
4 2 3 1 , 1
4 2 3 2 , 1
4 2 3 3 , 1
4 2 3 4 , 1
4 2 4 1 , 1
4 2 4 2 , 1
4 2 4 3 , 1
4 2 4 4 , 1
4 3 1 1 , 1
4 3 1 2 , 1
4 3 1 3 , 1
4 3 1 4 , 1
4 3 2 1 , 1
4 3 2 2 , 1
4 3 2 3 , 1
4 3 2 4 , 1
4 3 3 1 , 1
4 3 3 2 , 1
4 3 3 3 , 1
4 3 3 4 , 1
4 3 4 1 , 1
4 3 4 2 , 1
4 3 4 3 , 1
4 3 4 4 , 1
4 4 1 1 , 1
4 4 1 2 , 1
4 4 1 3 , 1
4 4 1 4 , 1
4 4 2 1 , 1
4 4 2 2 , 1
4 4 2 3 , 1
4 4 2 4 , 1
4 4 3 1 , 1
4 4 3 2 , 1
4 4 3 3 , 1
4 4 3 4 , 1
4 4 4 1 , 1
4 4 4 2 , 1
4 4 4 3 , 1
4 4 4 4 , 1
```